# Why long packageName results in a line break just before the import as quantifier?

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, sqldelight

In my Android multimodule project I have:
Module A:

```
sqldelight {
    SomeExampleDb {
        packageName = "com.example.exampleapp.feature.currency.datasource.example.localstorage"
    }
}
```

Module B:

```
sqldelight {
    SomeExampleDb {
        packageName = "com.example.exampleapp.feature.account.datasource.example.localstorage"
        dependency(project(":moduleA"))
    }
}
```

During build time, when compiler generates `SomeExampleDb` interface for module B, it results in such import:

```
import com.example.exampleapp.feature.currency.datasource.example.localstorage.SomeExampleDb as
    SomeExampleDb0
    
public interface SomeExampleDb : Transacter, SomeExampleDb0 {
 ...
}
```

(there is line break after `as`)
which results in such error:

```
e: {path to file}/SomeExampleDb.kt: (8, 101): Expecting identifier
```

Everything works fine when packageName is shorter. Is the maximum line length taken into account in any way during the build?

###### SQLDelight Version

1.5.2

###### Operating System

macOS Big Sur 11.2.3

###### Gradle Version

7.2

###### Kotlin Version

1.5.30

###### AGP Version

7.0.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is caused by the issue in kotlinpoet (api to generate kotlin files) which is used by sqldelight: https://github.com/square/kotlinpoet/issues/1169